# MySQL in Docker on Windows: World-writable files ignored

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

I'm using Docker-Compose with the [MySQL Image](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/) to fire up a MySQL database as part of a larger project.

As documented in the MySQL image's documentation, I'm mapping in a custom configuration file to `/etc/mysql/conf.d/config-file.cnf`:

```
database:
  environment:
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: foo
  ports:
    - "3306:3306"
  volumes:
    - "./mysql/conf.d/:/etc/mysql/conf.d"
  image: mysql:5.5
```

This works perfectly fine when running on Mac OS X as the host system (using `docker-machine`), but it fails when running on Windows (also using `docker-machine`). MySQL complains about the fact that the `/etc/mysql/conf.d/config-file.cnf` is world-writable

```
Warning: World-writable config file '/etc/mysql/conf.d/config-file.cnf' is ignored
```

When entering the database container, the file is indeed shown as having 0777 permission. This seems to be due to the host file system's permissions (Windows).

Is there any way to change this? I've tried mounting the volume in read-only mode, but the file still has the same permissions.

Any other way around this problem? At the moment, I'm mounting the file to another folder in the container and then copying/chmod'ing it to the required location as part of the startup command:

```
database:
  environment:
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: foo
  ports:
    - "3306:3306"
  volumes:
    - "./mysql/conf.d/:/usr/local/mysqlconf"
  image: mysql:5.5
  command: >
    bash -c "

    cp /usr/local/mysqlconf/*.cnf /etc/mysql/conf.d/
    && chmod 644 /etc/mysql/conf.d/*.cnf
    && /entrypoint.sh mysqld
    "
```

Is there a better way to solve this issue?

Comment: This answer seems to solve the issue. https://stackoverflow.com/a/64388578/1725871

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fixing World-writable MySql error in Docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37001272/fixing-world-writable-mysql-error-in-docker)

Comment: If you are coming to this question about MariaDB, this is fixed in recent MariaDB versions ([MDEV-27038](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-27038)) by marking the volume as read-only.

Answer (score -1):

When you start up a container with `-v`, `--volumes` or use `volumes:` in `docker-compose.yml`

```
docker run -v source:/dest:rw busybox ls -l /dest
```

Docker mounts the `source` directory from the *Linux VM* into a container as `/dest`. Docker mounted volumes only provide their own options `rw` and `r` and I think `z` for selinux. Owner and permission info will be passed through to the container exactly as the Linux VM sees them. If someone who clones your repo runs `docker` or `docker-compose` from their local host rather than on the VM, they will mount blank directories.

#### Docker Machine's `Users` share

A `docker-machine` created local VM will share your computer's local users directory by default. `C:\Users` on Windows and `/Users` on OSX. This is done as a VirtualBox shared folder called `Users`.  This share is then mounted on the Linux side via VirtualBox's `vboxsf` mount tool as `/Users` or maybe `/c/Users` via a Linux startup script `/etc/rc.d/vbox`.

When you `docker-machine ssh default` you should be able to see all your computers file at `/Users/nwinkler`.

This share allows `docker-compose` to reference a relative, local directory within `C:\Users` and have it work on the Linux VM. Outside of `C:\Users` the data doesn't exist on the VM.

#### World readable files

I believe what you are seeing is vboxsf's POSIX representation of a Windows file system. If you run:

```
docker-machine ssh default
$ cd /Users/nwinkler/path/to/mysql-docker
$ ls -l
$ docker run -v $PWD:/mysql busybox ls -l /mysql
```

You should see all your files as world writable. The only way to change the represented permissions is via the vboxsf mounted share.

The [mount options vboxsf](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man8/mount.vboxsf.8.html) provides are:

```
Available mount options are:
     rw                 mount writable (the default)
     ro                 mount read only
     uid=UID            set the default file owner user id to UID
     gid=GID            set the default file owner group id to GID
     ttl=TTL            set the "time to live" to TID for the dentry
     dmode=MODE         override the mode of all directories to (octal) MODE
     fmode=MODE         override the mode of all regular files to (octal) MODE
     umask=UMASK        set the umask to (octal) UMASK
     dmask=UMASK        set the umask applied to directories only
     fmask=UMASK        set the umask applied to regular files only
     iocharset CHARSET  use the character set CHARSET for I/O operations
                        (default set is utf8)
     convertcp CHARSET  convert the folder name from CHARSET to utf8
```

On the Docker Linux VM, edit `/etc/rc.d/box` and append the options to the `mountOptions` variable. These options will apply to all files and directories under `/Users` on that mount.

You could set an `fmask=007` to remove *other* permissions from all files or `fmode=750` to override all permissions for all files.

```
mountOptions='defaults,iocharset=utf8'
if grep -q '^docker:' /etc/passwd; then
    mountOptions="${mountOptions},uid=$(id -u docker),gid=$(id -g docker),fmask=007"
fi
```

If you ever upgrade or recreate your docker-machine VM you will need to do this again.

I tend to skip relying on virtualbox shares and have local files monitored and synchronised to my hosts on change (fsevents and rsync).

Comment: How would I use that in the above scenario? I can't provide `fmode` as an option in the docker-compose file... The `/etc/rc.d/vbox` file only sets up the `mountOptions` variable for use with the automounted `/Users` volumes, I don't think it's using it for any of the other volumes. How can I apply a different `fmask` value for the volumes mounted by docker-compose?

Comment: Mounting docker volumes (from the docker host to a container) only provides a `rw/r` option, otherwise docker volumes pass through whatever permissions are found on the docker host.  This answer is purely relating to the mounting of the VM Host users directory into the VM.  Is the `"./mysql/conf.d/` being mounted into the container coming from the `C:/Users` share? Do you access/edit those files in Windows?

Comment: Yes, the files are accessed/edited on Windows to add data to the MySQL container when it starts up. Once the container is running, the files are not edited on Windows anymore. The location of the files is not predefined, they are located wherever the user clones the Git repo holding the Docker-Compose repo. It could be under `C:/Users`, but it also could be in a different location on the user's machine.

Comment: Ok.. A user couldn't clone your repo into an arbitrary OSX/Windows location and have that mount into a container. That only works from inside `c:\users`.  I'll add some docker volume and docker-machine share detail.

Comment: @nwinkler hopefully that edit fills in the bits I brushed over.

Comment: Mh, the problem isn't when ssh'ing into the docker-machine VM, but within the individual containers. When I enter the `docker_database_1` container that docker-compose creates, I see the world-writable files there. Not sure whether your answer applies in that case.

Comment: Normally you get what's set on the docker host through to the container volume. If you are saying you see a difference between the Docker Host and the container, then that could be bug-ish

Comment: from the docker host do an `ls -l` and then a `docker run -v $PWD:/mysql busybox ls -l /mysql`. both listings should be the same.

Comment: This is a very detailed answer, but does not resolve the issue with the image.